# How to create a past-the-end iterator?

Tags: c++, tree, iterator

I have created a binary tree structure to store a bounded volume hierarchy, to make it easier to use (and safer) I created two iterators to complement it: breadth-first and depth-first.

The breadth-first iterator is essentially a wrapper for the underlying QList.  But I am stuck on the depth-first iterator (bidirectional only), I can handle the actual iteration around the tree, I just do not how to create a past-the-end iterator.

I can't just use the `QList::end()` because there is no guarantee the lowest-level rightmost node is also the rightmost node of the whole tree.  I'm reluctant to make a 'fake' BVH node that can tested for because it will involve a large code change (and probably overhead) to have the various node management mechanisms ignore the fake node, and disable a lot of the tree building automation (for example the parent of the fake node will have to be told it is a leaf).  But if this is the only way - then it is the only way.

Comment: I assumed this would be more a structural question.  The iterators, tree building constructs, and the BVH node itself, are many hundreds of lines of code.  What specifically would you like to see?

Comment: If you add the fake node, keep in mind that it doesn't actually need to connect to the tree in any way, or even actually exist (for some containers).  The only requirement is that your iterators must be able to go from it to the last, and from the last to it, which can be done in the _iterator's_ code.  (Depending on your structure.)

Comment: @cbamber85: Can you give a general overview of the container?  How is QList involved?  I think in your particular case though, you might be required to add an "end" node.

Comment: You're right, I missed the obvious.  When the tree is built I can  store the last node depth-wise, then when iterating I can detect if I'm at the last node, and if I go 'one past it' I know I'm at the 'end' iterator.  It's not an object, but a *state* of the iterator.  Stick your comment into an answer and I'll accept it!

Answer (score 0):

Having looked briefly at qlist.h, it appears that you won't be able to use the same end() for both iteration types.  But that's OK--you can use a null pointer or a static dummy or other techniques to make an end() iterator for your second iteration method.  I don't see why this would have to impact a huge amount of other code (most of which should just refer to end() without knowing its implementation details).

Comment: I can't use the `QList::end()` iterator because of the (possible) shape of the tree.  I thought I would have to modify the node's code in order to integrate a fake node properly, but Mooing Duck is onto something...

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just use `null` or something like this as end? This is at least what I would expect e.g. for a linked list structure.

Comment: No, because a NULL in the child links means that it is a leaf node.  Remember, I'm talking about a tree structure - there are lots of 'ends'.